# Aggregate Calculations Based on specific columns

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012, aggregation

I have a scenario, where need to generate aggregate values specified by values. The possible aggregations Min,Max, Avg and Mode

```
 Table

 ColumnA ColumnB  
  A        Min
  A        Mode
  A         Avg

  B        Max
  B        Avg

  C        Mode
  C        Min

  D         Avg

 Table 2

  ColumnC   ColumnD   ColumnE

    Pr1       1.00      A
    Pr2       2.00      A
    Pr3       3.00      A

    Pr1       4.00      B
    Pr2       5.00      B
    Pr4       1.00      B

    Pr5       2.00      C
    Pr6       6.00      C

    Pr7       4.00      D
    Pr8       5.00      D
```

Need to find Aggregations as defined in Table 1 and using values provided in columnD in table 2. The aggregations are grouped by each type of ColumnA. I would like to add part of stored procedure.

```
 Output should be

  ColumnF ColumnG  ColumnH  
  A        Min      1.00
  A        Mode     1.00 (if no mode exists take min value)
  A         Avg     2.00

  B        Max       5.00
  B        Avg        3.34

  C        Mode      2.00
  C        Min       2.00

  D         Avg       4.50
```

Comment: And how are these two tables related? There is no unique join key here... and what are you taking the aggregate of?

Comment: Tables are related with Column A and Column E

Answer (score 0):

Here is a brute force solution:

```
select t1.*,
       (case when column_b = 'min' then min_d
             when column_b = 'max' then max_d
             when column_b = 'mode' then mode_d
        end) as stat 
from t1 outer apply
     (select min(d) as min_d, max(d) as max_d, avg(d) as avg_d,
             (case when min(case when cnt = max_cnt then d end) = max(case when cnt = max_cnt then d end) 
                   then max(case when cnt = max_cnt then d end) 
                   else avg(d)
              end) as mode_d
      from (select t2.*, max(cnt) over () as max_cnt
            from (select t2.*, count(*) over (partition by d) as cnt
                  from table2 t2
                 ) t2
           ) t2
     ) t2;
```

The `mode` calculation is a bit tricky, but I think it does what you want.